# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable when dropping a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In `cols`, I want to drop the `class` column in the `breast_cancer_df`, which corresponds with the last column. But I'm getting `'DataFrame' object is not callable` error.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
import sklearn.datasets
import pandas as pd

breast_cancer = sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer()
breast_cancer_df = pd.DataFrame(
 data= np.c_[breast_cancer.data, [breast_cancer.target_names[v] for v in breast_cancer.target]],
 columns= list(breast_cancer.feature_names).append('class'))
cols = breast_cancer_df(columns=breast_cancer_df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
breast_cancer_df[cols] = breast_cancer_df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
g = sns.pairplot(breast_cancer_df, hue='class')

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-224-76d71f9352d8> in <module>
>       3  data= np.c_[breast_cancer.data, [breast_cancer.target_names[v] for v in breast_cancer.target]],
>       4  columns= list(breast_cancer.feature_names).append('class'))
> ----> 5 cols = breast_cancer_df(columns=breast_cancer_df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
>       6 breast_cancer_df[cols] = breast_cancer_df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
>       7 g = sns.pairplot(breast_cancer_df, hue='class')
> 
> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax/logic is wrong at several levels: `cols = breast_cancer_df(columns=breast_cancer_df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)`

1. A dataframe is not a function, you cannot use `breast_cancer_df(...)`. I imagine you want to slice here: `breast_cancer_df[...]` or use the `drop` method: `breast_cancer_df.drop(...)`
2. In `drop(...)` no need to combine `columns=...` and `axis=1`
3. If you use `inplace=True` in`drop(...)`, this will output nothing. There is no point in catching the output in `cols`.

Use:

```
breast_cancer_df = breast_cancer_df.iloc[:, :-1]
```

Or:

```
breast_cancer_df = breast_cancer_df.drop(columns=['class'])
```

*NB. Better not use `inplace` as it might get deprecated in the future*

Comment: When I try `breast_cancer_df = breast_cancer_df.iloc[:, :-1]`, I got an `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object` error.